# what's the meaning of service layer in java ee application I don't understand why?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

What's the meaning of service layer  why we must add service layer in our java EE MVC web application?

Comment: Service layer - is that part, where you put your business logic.

Comment: So you know about MVC? Service layer use to control transaction. It's good in practice to separate code into each tiers. The service layer would be for services that interact with the dB for example. Or it could be for dealing with JMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept is if you partition your code into different layers it is significantly easier to replace a technology or extend functionality.

A common structure is

- Presentation layer
- Business/service layer
- Data layer

With the each layer only depending on the layer directly below it. This would mean that the same application could run multiple user interfaces and perhaps a rest Interface and or a soap interface all using the same business logic.

Additionally if for instance you wished to change your database technology, there would only be a small part of the application which you would need up update.

Hopefully this answers your question well enough,  I could talk all day about this subject, however there is a lot of information available, just Google "separation of code".